# SwiftUI: How to parse JSON arrays from url using Alamofire?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

> Environments:
> macOS Ventura Developer Beta 3
> Xcode 14.0 beta 3
> MacBook Pro (13 inch M1, 2020)

> References: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMes-DVVJg4
> https://github.com/TuenTuenna/SwiftUI_Alamofire_RandomUser_tutorial/tree/01_Alamofire

Hello. I'm building a simple ESD for macOS using SwiftUI.
I'm gonna get informations from json by my server, and show informations what it got from api like this:
[GameESD_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IhaI.png)
[Game Informations, installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaWVu.png)

but it doesn't show anything like this:
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk0Hu.png)

This is my code. You can see entire code here: https://github.com/bmplatina/BitmapMac

game.json (JSON file to decode and parse, watch http://developer.prodbybitmap.com/game.json):

```
{
    "games": [
        {
            "gameIndex": 0,
            "gameTitle": "The Humanity",
            "gamePlatform": "Windows, macOS",
            "gameEngine": "Unity",
            "gameGenre": "어드벤처",
            "gameDeveloper": "입학했더니 무한 팀플과 과제가 쌓여버린 건에 대하여",
            "gamePublisher": "Bitmap Production",
            "isEarlyAccess": true,
            "gameReleasedDate": 20211210,
            "gameWebsite": "http://prodbybitmap.com/wiki/The%20Humanity",
            "gameImageURL": "http://www.prodbybitmap.com/w/images/9/99/TheHumanityPoster1.png",
            "gameDescription": "Desc"
        },

        {
            "gameIndex": 1,
            "gameTitle": "OX",
            "gamePlatform": "Windows",
            "gameEngine": "Unreal Engine 5",
            "gameGenre": "몰입형 VR 퍼즐 게임",
            "gameDeveloper": "Team. Assertive",
            "gamePublisher": "ENTER, Bitmap Production",
            "isEarlyAccess": true,
            "gameReleasedDate": 20220624,
            "gameWebsite": "http://prodbybitmap.com/wiki/OX",
            "gameImageURL": "http://www.prodbybitmap.com/w/images/f/f9/OX_CMYK.JPG",
            "gameDescription": "Desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

GameESD_View.swift:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct GameESD_View: View {
    @State private var searchField: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var gameViewmodel = gameInfoViewmodel()
    
    let gameInfoExam = exampleGameInfo()
    let columnLayout = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 4)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.init(hex: "4188F1"))
                    .frame(height: 42)
                    .shadow(radius: 4)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image("bitmapWebLogo")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(height: 30)
                    Spacer()
//                    if true {
//                        Text("Online")
//                    }
//                    else {
//                        Text("Offline Mode")
//                    }
                    TextField("Filter".localized(), text: $searchField)
                }
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Seoul Institute of the Arts Collection")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .padding([.top, .leading])
                    Text("collection.")
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Divider()
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columnLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                        // List(gameViewmodel.gameInfos) { aGameInfos in }
                        ForEach(0..<gameViewmodel.gameInfos.count, id: \.self) { aGameInfos in
                            GameButtons(gameViewmodel.gameInfos[aGameInfos])
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    Text("Other Games")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .padding([.top, .leading])
                    Text("여러 창작자의 다양한 인디 컨텐츠.")
                        .padding(.leading)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Games".localized())
        }
    }
}

struct GameButtons: View {
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    var gameInfos: gameInfo
    
    init(_ gameInfos: gameInfo) {
        self.gameInfos = gameInfos
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { }
        Button {
            showingPopover = true
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Image("unknownImage")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 300)
                URLImage(URL(string: gameInfos.gameImageURL)!) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width:300)
                }
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, Color.black.opacity(0.5)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).frame(width: 300, height: 424)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(gameInfos.gameTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                    Divider()
                    Text("Dev".localized() + ": " + gameInfos.gameDeveloper)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(width:256)
                .padding()
            }
            .cornerRadius(24)
            .shadow(radius: 4)
            .padding()
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Bitmap Games")
                            .font(Font.largeTitle)
                            .bold()
                        Text("Bitmap Store".localized())
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { showingPopover = false }) {
                        Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
                .padding()
                GameDetailsView(gameIndex: gameInfos.gameIndex)
            }
            .frame(width: 1000, height: 600)
            .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}

struct GameDetailsView: View {
    @State private var installAlert = false
    
    let gameInfo: exampleGameInfo = exampleGameInfo()
    var gameIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Temp")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ESD_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameESD_View()
        // digitalArtsFestivalWebView()
    }
}
#endif
```

FetchGameInformation.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Alamofire

struct gameInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var gameIndex: Int
    var gameTitle: String
    var gamePlatform: String
    var gameEngine: String
    var gameGenre: String
    var gameDeveloper: String
    var gamePublisher: String
    var isEarlyAccess: Bool
    var gameReleasedDate: Int
    var gameWebsite: String
    var gameImageURL: String
    var gameDescription: String
    
    var gameImage: URL {
        get {
            URL(string: gameImageURL)!
        }
    }
    static func makeDummy() -> Self {
        print(#fileID, #function, #line, "")
        return gameInfo(gameIndex: 1, gameTitle: "OX", gamePlatform: "Windows", gameEngine: "Unreal Engine 5", gameGenre: "몰입형 VR 퍼즐 게임", gameDeveloper: "Team. Assertive", gamePublisher: "ENTER, Bitmap Production", isEarlyAccess: true, gameReleasedDate: 20220624, gameWebsite: "http://prodbybitmap.com/wiki/OX", gameImageURL: "http://www.prodbybitmap.com/w/images/f/f9/OX_CMYK.JPG", gameDescription: "This is Description")
    }
}

struct gameResult: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var games: [gameInfo]
    var description: String {
        return "gameInfo.count: \(games.count)"
    }
}

struct gamesResponse: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var games: [gameInfo]
    
    var description: String {
        return "games.count: \(games.count) / info : \(games[0].gameTitle)"
    }
}

class gameInfoViewmodel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: Properties
    var subscription = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var gameInfos = [gameInfo]()
    
    var url = "http://developer.prodbybitmap.com/game.json"
    
    init() {
        print(#fileID, #function, #line, "")
        fetchGameInfo()
    }
    
    func fetchGameInfo() {
        print(#fileID, #function, #line, "")
        AF.request(url, method: .get)
            .publishDecodable(type: gamesResponse.self)
            .compactMap { $0.value }
            .map { $0.games }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("Datastream Done")
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self](receivedValue: [gameInfo]) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                print("Data Value: \(receivedValue.description)")
                self.gameInfos = receivedValue
            }).store(in: &subscription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `print("Data Value: \(receivedValue.description)")` printed? Does it seems to have the correct values? is your issue the JSON parsing? The showing part?

Comment: Nope. It just says Datastream Done

Comment: In `sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in`, you might want to check the value of `completion` if there is an error... With a `switch completion: case .failure(let error): print("Error: \(error)"), case ...}` for instance?

Comment: change `var id = UUID()` to `let id = UUID()` in `gameInfo`. There is no `id` in the json data, the `let` will ignore `id` when decoding. You can also use `enum CodingKeys...`.

Comment: Note Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server? Once you have set this, the decoding with the change I mentioned (`let id = UUID()`), works well for me.

Comment: ye changing id to let from var works. Thanks!